# Infragistics adding a newline in text

Tags: html, asp.net, text, infragistics

I have a `contenttabitem` as shown below:

```
<ig:ContentTabItem runat="server" ScrollBars="Hidden" Text="aaabbb"></ig:ContentTabItem>
```

I'm trying to have a newline between aaa and bbb. I tried with `\r\n` or `\n` or `System.Environment.NewLine` but none works

Comment: have you tried a <br /> tag in the text?

Comment: Yes none of them works

Comment: I was able to get this to work though I needed to increase the height of the tab headers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 
 tag to the ContentTabItem's Text:

```
<ig:ContentTabItem runat="server" Text="Line 1<br />Line 2"></ig:ContentTabItem>
```

By default you will only see one line of text unless you also add css to make the tab headers taller:

```
<style>
    .igtab_THHolder 
    {
        height: 45px;
    }
    .igtab_THTab 
    {
        height: 44px;    
    }
</style>
```